# Create TABLE in many Postgres schemas with a single command

Tags: postgresql, events, triggers, synchronization, schema

I have two schemas in my Postgres BOOK database, MSPRESS and ORELLY.
I want to create the same table in two schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE MSPRRESS.BOOK(title TEXT, author TEXT);
CREATE TABLE ORELLY.BOOK(title TEXT, author TEXT);
```

Now, I want to create the same table in all my schemas with a single command.

To accomplish this, I thought about event triggers available in Postgres 9.3 (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/event-triggers.html). Intercepting CREATE TABLE command by my event trigger, I thought to determine name of table and schema in which it is created and just repeat the same command for all available schemas. Sadly, event trigger procedure does not get name of table being created.

Is there a way to 'real-time' synchronization of Postgres schema?

Comment: Have you considered a `DO` block in plgpsql, iterating over the schemas? That's a single command for a SQL client.

Answer (score 1):

Currently [only `TG_EVENT` and `TG_TAG`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Event_Triggers#How_to_expose_Information_to_Event_Triggers_Functions) is available from an event trigger, but this feature will likely be expanded. In the meantime, you can query [information_schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/information-schema.html) for differences and try to add every table, where its missing; but don't forget that this *synchronization* will also trigger several event triggers, so you should do it carefully.

But if you just want to build several schemas with the same structure (without further synchronization), you could just write schema-less queries to build them & run it on every schema one-by-one, after changing [search path](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) with [`SET search_path` / `SET SCHEMA`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-set.html).

Comment: Examining information_schema may be a solution for CREATE TABLE but for ALTER TABLE it's ambiguous. I'd like all DDL-commands (CREATE, ALTER, DROP) in one scheme to be reflected in all schemas.

Comment: But still, there's no other way to do it. `information_schema` is your best shot until event triggers will be expanded. Unless you can do nasty things with the `parsetree` in `C` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/event-trigger-interface.html

Comment: Example of doing nasty things?

Comment: Write an event trigger in `C`, where you have the whole parse tree of the DDL (follow the link). Not much better than querying `information_schema` though.

Comment: I have followed. How does the parsing tree, for, for instance, CREATE TABLE  look?

Comment: I haven't write any before. I have no other information than what anyone can find in the docs.